# updateDisplayName in action without reloading simulator

Tags: flutter, firebase

In my code, I have firebase auth and I get the current user as:

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```

To display the user name in a Text, just use `Text(user.displayName)`

To test the update functionality, I created a simple button and on onPressed I have

```
user.updateDisplayName('Test').then((_) =>user.reload());
```

How to "notify" the `Text` that the data has changed and change it without needing to reload the simulator?

--> this code is in a drawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Flutter, you'll need to store the value you want to re-render in the `State` of a stateful widget, call `setState()` when the value is updated, and then render it from there in your `build` method.

I recommend checking the documentation on [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) for an example of this, and more explanation than I can ever repeat here.